# Google App script Api to get the range of Pivot table in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a chart from the Pivot table. But there is no way to know the range of Pivot table to create a chart from it.

Are there any workarounds to create a chart from the pivot table?

**Edit**

```
var pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
var pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(3);
var pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(12, 
SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.SUM);
```

A pivot table is successfully created by using the above three lines, but I don't know how to get the entire range of the pivot table. I mean the cell locations in which the pivot table is currently residing.

I need the pivot table range to create a chart from it. Below are the lines to create it:

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
.addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:B8"))  //I need to pass pivot table range here
.setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
.build();
sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: *But there is no way to know the range of Pivot table to create a chart from it.* Show your research to accompany this claim

Comment: @TheMaster, please look into this ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154063886#comment1. I hope it satisfies you.

Comment: No it doesn't. Second comment there explains the next steps. Have you looked into the link and researched what you might do from the methods available?

Comment: @TheMaster, "You know that the table starts with A1 and that the pivot table has two columns. Why not pass the range "A:B"?" - how can we say the pivot table can only have two columns? It would change based on the row groups and column groups added to the pivot configuration.
I omitted the code, because it was the same as the documentation. Obviously, I have done research on it and haven't been able to reach the solution. And thanks for the downvote.

Comment: use [`getDataRegion()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdataregion) on A1.

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks for your suggestion, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just as explained in this link [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154063886#comment4), after creating the `Pivot Table` you can simply see where it ends and retrieve the range needed or mark the end of it by using another variable.

Both these options offer you the possibility of retrieving the range of the `Pivot Table` in order to create the `Chart`.

**Reference**

- [Google Issue Tracker Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154063886#comment4);

Comment: As mentioned by @TheMaster, I have used https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdataregion on the location of the pivot table say A! to get the entire range.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Given a pivotTable, you can get the range using the following:

```
const pivotTableRange = pivotTable.getAnchorCell().getDataRegion();
```

This assumes that the pivottable is surrounded by empty cells, otherwise, it might also include data from any other non-empty cell.